# make function run when click

Tags: javascript, angular

I want make blink a icon when I click on it

My ts file

```
  onBlink() {
    this.action = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.action = false;
    }, 1000)
    return this.action
  };
```

My HTML file
action is declare in ts as any type

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
 <mat-icon (click)="element.action = onBlink()" class="icon bulb" 
     [ngClass]="{
     'blink_me': element.action ,
     '': element.action === false}
     ">wb_incandescent</mat-icon>
</td>
```

Comment: Explain the issue? The idea looks sound and I'm not  sure what the problem is

Comment: When I click I want attribute a class to make the icon blink, after that I need to remove this class for make possible another click on the icon and blink again.

Comment: what is element?

Comment: because I use angular material table, element is use to have each of value of my object

Comment: I edit my code with the new one, it works but just one time, because the class attribute by ngClass doesn't remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your element to the ts from the html:

```
<mat-icon (click)="onBlink(element)" class="icon bulb" [ngClass]="element.action ? 'blink_me': ''">wb_incandescent</mat-icon>
```

Then in your ts:

```
onBlink(element) {
  element.action = true
  console.log('blink true');
  setTimeout(() => {
    element.action = false;
    console.log('blink false')
  },1000)
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work because when i remove element from Html, all the icons of my table blink at the same time, and  I can't use element in my ts file because it generated by the html

Comment: Ah then you need to pass the value of your element to your onblink method. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The ideia is fine, i have just changed the syntax a little bit:

`````
<mat-icon
  (click)="onBlink()"
  class="icon bulb"
  [ngClass]="{ 'blink_me': action }">
  wb_incandescent
</mat-icon>
````
`````